# Can merging 4 sites into 1 help?

Tags: seo, domains, multiple-domains, branding, multi-subdomains

The company I work for has 4 websites. There is a related theme to them (all IT services or web design / development). All have unique content.

I am hearing more and more that these need to be brought in under one domain and managed as one.

In order for this to happen I will need to get the comapny to 'buy into' this way of thinking. And what Owners and Directors need to hear are facts!

Can anyone supply any facts (or point me in the right direction) that I can report back as to why merging the 4 sites will benefit the company.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Similar question about ranking losses after merging multiple domains: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43197/merging-multiple-top-level-domains-into-a-single-domain

Answer (score 2):

The answer is Yes and No...

It's easier to rank a website that is all about Web Design than it is to rank a website that is about Computer Repairs, Network Installs and Web Design since the Authority gets a little diluted but this isn't to say it won't rank better.

Personally Web Design and Web Development is a great pair for Authority and merging the sites could be a huge plus for your business, The IT Services I would keep it on its own domain unless its IT Services related to Web Services such as Web Design (I.E Hosting.) Google is great at working which topics tie into one and another, so if the topic doesn't fit don't include it.

I used to run a site that had similar, once I moved off IT Services such as networking installs and VoIP installs I found that my rankings on Web Design shoot though the roof, I still need to get around to doing this on one of my sites but something I'm definitely going to do this year.

It's true what they say that if your site is about Web Design then don't blog about Cats etc because it doesn't help your rankings at all and in some cases dilutes the authority of the site.

It's important to note there's no right or wrong answer to your question because it is possible to rank your sites either way, take Amazon as a prime example - They are diluted to hell but due to the sheer amount of backlinks they can be found on front pages all over.... But what I find personally is that Amazon doesn't often make the top 2-3 while the more Authority sites do... Personally I aim for the best and I believe to be the best you need to be an authority with as little dilution as possible, but again I must express there's no right answer to your question....